# Get correct Kekkak256 of an uploaded file in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, keccak

I am using keccak256 npm module to calculate the hash of an uploaded file. I verify the correctness and I see that the given hash does not correspond to the ones compared on some online hash calculators (such as: [this](https://www.browserling.com/tools/sha3-hash) or [this](https://keccak-256.cloxy.net) or [this](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html) ).

The code I run is:

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const keccak256 = require('keccak256');
const formidable = require('formidable'),
    http = require('http'),
    util = require('util');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html', {root: __dirname })
});


router.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('received upload saved in: ' + files.upload.path + '\n\n');
      var readStream = fs.createReadStream(files.upload.path);
      //res.write(readStream);
      console.log(keccak256(readStream).toString('hex'))
      res.end("");

    });

    return;
});
```

Can anyone kindly explain to me where I am wrong and how I can correct it?

Comment: Something to do with using `'hello'` instead of the contents of the file?

Comment:  I corrected, but I get `/node_modules/keccak256/dist/index.js:34
      throw new Error('invalid type'); Error: invalid type
    at toBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using [NPM `sha-3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha3):

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const formidable = require('formidable'),
    http = require('http'),
    util = require('util');
const { Keccak } = require('sha3');
const hash = new Keccak(256);

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html', {root: __dirname })
});


router.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('received upload saved in: ' + files.upload.path + '\n\n');
      var file = fs.readFileSync(files.upload.path);
      hash.update(file);
      console.log(hash.digest('hex'));
      res.end("");

    });

    return;
});
```

Now it works fine.